# Find the type of the Object, probably System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

Tags: c#, collections

I am not sure why the condition below is not getting fulfilled.

```
 else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>))
```

Obj is an object of type `Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>)`

When I am executing the above code, it does not enter inside the `else if` condition.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing them using `"=="` you can compare them with [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword, [IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) Method, and [Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) any of this will work for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would switch it to using the is keyword, so

```
else if (obj is Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>)
```

which will match if obj has that type somewhere in its ancestry. If you try to equal only on the exact types it may not work.

If that still doesn't work, then I'd put the types into variables and check them in the debugger to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

Tested just now.

```
object obj = new Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>();
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection>))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
```

Its all right. Try to write

```
Type objType = obj.GetType();
```

and see what you get.